When is $\mathbb E[F(S)\mid S=s]= \mathbb E[F(s)]$ true?
Let $S$ be a discrete random variable on a set $\mathcal S$. Moreover, let $F(s)$ be another random variable (say in $L^1$) for each $s\in\mathcal S$.
Now consider some $s\in\mathcal S$. I am looking for a sufficient condition under which it is true that
\begin{equation}
\mathbb E\left[F(S)\mid S=s\right] = \mathbb E[F(s)].
\end{equation}
I would also be interested in counter examples. If need be I can also give a more specific setting.
Understanding so far: The left-hand-side is in general of course a random variable, while the right-hand-side is deterministic (depending on $s$). So it shouldn't be true in general. Assuming $\mathbb P(S=s)>0$ we may rewrite the equation to be
\begin{equation}
\mathbb E[F(s)\cdot 1_{S=s}] = \mathbb E[F(s)]\cdot \mathbb E[1_{S=s}].
\end{equation}
Thus, an independence assumption (uncorrelated would even be enough here) like "$F(s)$ and $1_{S=s}$ are independent" would work. However, I don't see why this should be the case, as the random variables $F(s)$ and $1_{S=s}$ both depend on the fixed $s$.
Any help is appreciated!

If you know the distribution of $F(s)$ and so know $\mathbb E[F(s)]$  for each $s$ then $\mathbb E\left[F(S)\mid S=s\right] = \mathbb E[F(s)]$ is reasonable.  The problem comes when you only know the distribution of $(F,S)$ and if you have $\mathbb P(S=s)=0$ then you may encounter the Borel–Kolmogorov paradox.

This is true if $F(t)$ is independent of $S$ for all fixed $t$ (because this implies $F(t)$ is independent of $1_{S=t}$). For instance, if you're generating $S$ and the random function $F$ independently, then plugging the former into the latter, then the equation holds. But if they're not independent, then knowing $S$ might tell you something about what the random function $F$ was, and the equation might not hold.

@Ziv I think the question is interested in $F$ not being independent of $S$.

Isn't it true that, as $S$ is discrete, it can only take finite or countably many values so that by definition $\mathbb{E}1_{S=s}\mathbb{E}(F(S)\mid S=s)=\sum_{s'\in \mathcal{S}}\mathbb{E}1_{S=s}F(s')=\mathbb{E}F(s)$?

A related (but different) property is discussed at Expectation of random variable indexed by random variable.

$E[F(S)\mid S=s]=E[F(s)\mid S=s]=E[F(s)]$, where the last equality is true if F(s) and S are independent.


I am looking for a sufficient condition under which it is true that $$\Bbb E[F(S)\mid S=s] = \Bbb E[F(s)]$$

$S$ can be seen as a "selector" r.v., each value of which just picks out one r.v. from a family of r.v.s $\{F(s)\}_{s\in\mathcal S}$.  A sufficient condition for the above equation is that $S$ be independent of $\{F(s)\}_{s\in\mathcal S}$; i.e., that $S$ be independent of $F(s)$ for each $s\in\mathcal S$.
NB: The composite r.v. $F(S)$ is not generally a member of the family $\{F(s)\}_{s\in\mathcal S}$.
Here's a simple counterexample that illustrates this, and in which the above equation fails to hold, due to extreme dependency:
Let $F(0), F(1)$ be i.i.d. Bernoulli$({1\over2})$, and define $S:=1-F(1)$, with $\mathcal S=\{0,1\}$. Then $\Bbb E[F(S)\mid S=1]=\Bbb E[F(1)\mid S=1]=\Bbb E[0\mid S=1]=0\ne \Bbb E[F(1)].$
Due to the explicit dependency of $S=1-F(1)$, it's easy to see that in fact $F(S)=F(0)\cdot F(1)$:
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\text{$F(0)$} & \text{$F(1)$} & \text{$S=1-F(1)$} & \text{$F(S)$} \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
\hline
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
\hline
1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
\hline
1 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
\hline
\end{array} 
$$

The left-hand-side is in general of course a random variable, while the right-hand-side is deterministic (depending on $s$). So it shouldn't be true in general.

For each $s\in\mathcal{S}$, each side is a real number, thus defining on each side a function (r.v.) $\mathcal S\to\Bbb R$.

an independence assumption (uncorrelated would even be enough here) like "$F(s)$ and $1_{S=s}$ are independent" would work. However, I don't see why this should be the case, as the random variables $F(s)$ and $1_{S=s}$ both depend on the fixed $s$.

It's entirely possible that for all $s\in\mathcal S$, the r.v. ${\bf1}_{\{S=s\}}$ is independent of the r.v. $F(s);$ e.g., this is the case if the family $\{F(s)\}_{s\in\mathcal S}$ is i.i.d. and, independently, $S\sim\text{Uniform}$ on finite $\mathcal S$. (The counterexample given above would be like this if we change it to have, independently, $S\sim$ Uniform on $\{0,1\}$: then $F(0)$ is independent of whether $\{S=0\}$ occurs, and $F(1)$ is independent of whether $\{S=1\}$ occurs.)
